# Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException - Error: Expected end of string, got 'WHERE'

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

There is a function I'm using to get next photo in gallery:

```
$q = "SELECT i FROM GalleryModule\Image i WHERE i.id = (SELECT MIN(p.id) FROM GalleryModule\Image p WHERE p.id > :id ORDER BY p.position, p.id DESC) WHERE i.gallery = :gallery";
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($q);
    $query->setMaxResults(1);
    $query->setParameters(array(
        'id' => $image->getId(),
        'gallery' => $image->getGallery()->getId()
    ));
    return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
```

The error I'm still facing:

```
Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException
```

[Syntax Error] line 0, col 143: Error: Expected end of string, got 'WHERE'

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple where's

Perhaps u mean this:

```
SELECT i FROM GalleryModule\Image i 
WHERE i.id = 
    (SELECT MIN(p.id) 
    FROM GalleryModule\Image p 
    WHERE p.id > :id ORDER BY p.position, p.id DESC) 
AND i.gallery = :gallery
```

Comment: Oh yes, you're absolutely right. Thanks a lot! I was trying to rewrite the query from DIBI fluent code and there was sth like `->where('query1')->where('query2')`. And it stands for `WHERE query1 AND query2` :)